# Issue creating new git repo from terminal?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get more familiar with git. I have had no issues creating a repo on github and then cloning it to my machine either through http or ssh. Once I've cloned it I can then edit files locally and push the changes back no problem. When trying to create a new repo on my machine and then push this to git, is where my problems begin. I followed the steps from github [here](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) but get the following error message

```
git push origin masterfatal: https://github.com/robocode/testgit.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I have checked that my local PATH is pointing to git, and to the receive and upload packs also and this seems fine, echoing my PATH variable contains the following git paths

```
:/usr/bin/git-upload-pack:/usr/bin/git:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually *create* the repository in your GitHub account first. It is not enough to just push to GitHub to get it created. Instead log into GitHub, and choose the “Create a new repo” (third from the right, at the top). Then after the repository is created, you can start to push things into it.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood then. That process had been working fine for me, I assumed I could then create a repo locally and push that but if that's not possible no wonder it hasn't been working